# The concept of delayed abstraction: VerX

Tags: contract-verification

I am trying to understand the concept of delayed abstraction mentioned in paper [416] at:
[Link of VerX](https://files.sri.inf.ethz.ch/website/papers/sp20-verx.pdf)

VerX tool uses the concept of delayed abstraction for SC verification. Is Delayed abstraction related to automatic generation of abstractions? I can’t unerstand this concept:

To verify a Past LTL specification of a bundle of contracts C
we apply abstract interpretation over a symbolic domain.
We employ predicate abstraction [35] but without the usual
conversion to boolean programs. Our approach is similar to
that of Flanagan and Qadeer [32] where two transformers are
alternated: precise symbolic transformers to handle individual
commands, and an imprecise transformer to ensure convergence.
In contrast, classic abstraction applies an imprecise
transformer at every step. Hence, we call the precise/imprecise
approach delayed abstraction.

Somebody please guide me.
Zulfi.